# How to find the executable files in the current directory and find out their extensions?

Tags: bash, find

I need to find all executable files from /bin. How to do it using

```
find . -executable
```

and how to check if the file is script (for example, sh, pl, bash)?

Comment: add `-type f` to your find command to weed out subdirectories.

Comment: Is there any file in /bin which isn't executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                    

for file in `find /bin` ; do                                                                                                                                   
    if [ -x $file ] ; then                                                                                                                                     
        file $file                                                                                                                                             
    fi                                                                                                                                                         
done
```

and even better to do

```
find /bin -type f -perm +111 -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

Answer (score 1):

`find /bin/ -executable` returns all executable files from `/bin/` directory.

To filtering extension there are usable `-name` flag.  For example, `find /bin/ -executable -name "*.sh"` returns `sh`-scripts.

**UPD**:

If file is not a binary file and do not have extension, it's possible to figured out it's type from shabang.

For example `find ~/bin/ -executable | xargs grep --files-with-matches '#!/bin/bash'` returns files from `~/bin/` directory, which contains `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: thanks, but how to determine script type if file doesn't have extension?

Comment: Grepping for '#!/bin/bash' has the risk of false positives, while missing files that use /bin/sh. You're better off using the `file` command to figure out what kind of executable a file is.

Comment: Right, shabang grepping is kinda kludge with `file`s response. Didn't know about that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the scripts shell

```
find . -type f -executable | xargs file -i | grep x-shellscript | cut -d":" -f1
```

To find all the executable

```
find . -type f -executable | xargs file -i | grep x-exec | cut -d":" -f1
```

To find all the shared libraries

```
find . -type f -executable | xargs file -i | grep x-sharedlib | cut -d":" -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me & thought of sharing...

```
find ./ -type f -name "*" -exec sh -c '
    case "$(head -n 1 "$1")" in
      ?ELF*) exit 0;;
      MZ*) exit 0;;
      #!*/ocamlrun*)exit0;;
    esac
exit 1
' sh {} \; -print
```